# mailx -a is not working to send html email in Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, email, solaris

I am trying to sending an email in html format. but its not working.

```
echo "<html><b>Hello</b></html>" | mailx -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s "Testing" me@xmple.com
```

Returns :

```
mail: illegal option -- a
mail: Usage: [-ehpPqr] [-f file] [-x debuglevel]
or      [-tw] [-m message_type] [-T file] [-x debuglevel] persons
or      [-x debuglevel]
```

but the same command is working with out -a option which is not a html.

```
echo "<html><b>Hello</b></html>" | mailx -s "Testing" me@xmple.com
```

Comment: Your `mailx` doesn't seem to support `-a`.  What distro are you using?

Comment: @Flup: look at this. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/how-do-i-send-html-email-using-linux-mail-command

Comment: @Flup : what do you mean by distro

Comment: The usage output you've included above indicates that your `mailx` doesn't support `-a`.  We need to know what kind of Linux -- Ubuntu, Debian, Mint, CentOS etc -- and which version you're using so we can help.

Comment: @Flup : I am using solaris

Comment: Ah! You confused me because you tagged your question 'linux'.  I'm afraid the Solaris version of `mailx` doesn't support the `-a` option.

Comment: @Flup : so what is the option now

Comment: There is no option in Solaris mailx for that - you'll need to install a different mail program to send HTML mail, or learn to write full headers yourself to send via `/usr/lib/sendmail`.

Answer (score 1):

The `-a` is a file attachment in the GNU version of `mailx`. Most other versions of `mailx` don't support that option since they're mainly concerned with text-based mail. There is not much you can do to get this to work. Here are some options:

If this is merely text you want to email, simply redirect it to the mail command:

```
$ mailx -s "Here's the info" bob ted alice < file.txt
```

In the old days, we would [uuencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) the file. This would convert any file to a 64 character subset of ASCII characters that all computers understood. (Many computers in the old days only had 6-byte characters, thus 64 characters). You would `uuencode` the file, then attach it to the email. The recipient would save the attachment and `uudecode` the file.

```
$ uuencode -o file.uuencode file.jpg file.jpg
$ mailx -s "Here's the jpg (uuencoded) bob ted alice < file.uuencode
```

Or, you can use a scripting language like PHP, Perl, or Python that can do MIME encoded mail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but My question is to use HTML format in unix itself

Comment: Your only real solution is to use Python or Perl which both have with MIME encoding email modules. Some systems have the ability to use `uuencode` to produce MIME64 encoding instead of UUENCODE encoding. However, you'd have to use munge the correct MIME encoding headers and lines yourself. That's going to be tricky. However, it might be possible.